# Iterating a model in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

In OpenMDAO, within an optimisation driver, is there any way to repeat/iterate a part of the model (a group) over a range of inputs?

I'm developing an optimisation framework built on OpenMDAO. So far, I have been running the optimisation for one specific load case, and now I would like to extend it to optimising for an objective that is calculated as an average over a number of load cases.

For each set of design variables, I would like to run the model inside a for loop (as in `for load_case in load_cases`), record the result of each iteration, and then average them out to get the value of the objective for the driver. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggested solution is fine. You have the right idea. I would just suggest that the two duplicate cost classes are not needed.

```
import openmdao.api as om

class Cost(om.ExplicitComponent):
    ''' normally defined in a separate script for convenience '''

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', val=0)
        self.add_input('y', val=0)
        self.add_output('cost', val=0, units='USD')
        
    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        cost_steel = inputs['x']
        cost_ballast = inputs['y']

        cost = cost_steel + cost_ballast

        outputs['cost'] = cost
                 

class MDA(om.Group):

    class ObjCmp(om.ExplicitComponent):
        
        def setup(self):
            self.add_input('cost_1', val=0, units='USD')
            self.add_input('cost_2', val=0, units='USD')
            self.add_output('obj', val=0.0, units='USD')

        def setup_partials(self):
            self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

        def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
            outputs['obj'] =  inputs['cost_1'] + inputs['cost_2']

    def setup(self):     
        group_ls = self.add_subsystem('ls1', om.Group(), promotes_inputs=['x','y'],
                            promotes_outputs=['cost_1']) 

        group_ls.add_subsystem('Cost1', Cost(), promotes_inputs=['x','y'],
                           promotes_outputs=[('cost', 'cost_1')])
                           
        group_ls.add_subsystem('Cost2', Cost(), promotes_inputs=['x','y'],
                           promotes_outputs=[('cost', 'cost_2')])
        
        self.add_subsystem('obj_cmp', self.ObjCmp(), promotes_inputs=['cost_1','cost_2'],
                           promotes_outputs=['obj'])


# build the model
prob = om.Problem(model=MDA())
model = prob.model

model.add_design_var('x', lower=0.1, upper=1)
model.add_design_var('y', lower=0.1, upper=1)
model.add_objective('obj')

# setup the optimization
prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.setup()

# run the optimization
prob.set_val('x', .5)
prob.set_val('y', .5)

prob.run_driver()

# minimum value
print(prob.get_val('obj'))

# location of the minimum
print(prob.get_val('x'))
print(prob.get_val('y'))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

There seems to be a problem with the n2 plot, after modifying the framework according to the above, it stopped showing one of my subgroups as a group (the n2 tool does not show it despite the summary tool showing it, and the code itself running as if it was a group with a NL solver, like it should, so it looks like a potential problem with n2 tool?). My model is confidential so I cannot share it here, but happy to give any details or go through it in a call if needed.

Comment: Its hard for me to guess what the problem is with the N2 is without some way to reproduce it. You could always remove all the actual compute code from the components and scramble the variable names. That way you can submit a bug report to the development team.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a way that would let you compute derivatives, I would recommend a multi-point approach.

Make a group class for your model. Then for each load-case you create one instance of it in the model. Then all the various load cases exist at the same time, and you can do any kind of aggregation you want (e.g. [the KS function component)](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.26.0/features/building_blocks/components/ks_comp.html). This approach has the advantage of being simple and easy to implement. Its downside is that it uses a relatively larger amount of memory. If you have less than 10 load cases to consider its the right approach (even if you're using FEA and CFD).

If you have many many load cases, then you might want to actually consider a for loop style model. This is more complex to implement, requiring the use of a [sub-problem](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/RevHack2020/blob/master/solution_approaches/sub_problems.md). This is needed so that you can add the for loop in a way that OpenMDAO understands. Effectively, you build your model of a single load case, add it to a stand-alone problem. Then instantiate that problem INSIDE a component. Then you can wrap a for loop around a call to `run_model` of that sub-problem and set up all your load cases. You have to be really careful about how you handle data passing between the parent component and the sub-problem, and the same goes for derivatives. This approach scales to larger numbers of load cases better, but is more complex to implement by a good bit. I really recommend you try the multi-point approach first.

As of OpenMDAO v3.26.0 there is no official sub-problem implementation you can use in OpenMDAO. I know the dev-team is working on one, but it hasn't be released yet. So you have to follow the guide f[rom the 2020 reverse hackathon and roll your own](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/RevHack2020/blob/master/solution_approaches/sub_problems.md).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any example of the 1st approach? I am not sure how to handle the instances and their outputs. For N load-cases, within the model, do I add N subsystems in the setup?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above reply, I was able to implement the code below (very simplified reproducible example). Is this the correct implementation of the multi-point you suggested, or is there a better way that would allow to avoid redefining the Cost class for each load case separately?

```
import openmdao.api as om

class Cost1(om.ExplicitComponent):
    ''' normally defined in a separate script for convenience '''

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', val=0)
        self.add_input('y', val=0)
        self.add_output('cost_1', val=0, units='USD')
        
    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        cost_steel = inputs['x']
        cost_ballast = inputs['y']

        cost = cost_steel + cost_ballast

        outputs['cost_1'] = cost
        
class Cost2(om.ExplicitComponent):
    ''' normally defined in a separate script for convenience '''

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', val=0)
        self.add_input('y', val=0)
        self.add_output('cost_2', val=0, units='USD')
        
    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        cost_steel = inputs['x']
        cost_ballast = inputs['y']

        cost = cost_steel + cost_ballast

        outputs['cost_2'] = cost
                 

class MDA(om.Group):

    class ObjCmp(om.ExplicitComponent):
        
        def setup(self):
            self.add_input('cost_1', val=0, units='USD')
            self.add_input('cost_2', val=0, units='USD')
            self.add_output('obj', val=0.0, units='USD')

        def setup_partials(self):
            self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

        def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
            outputs['obj'] =  inputs['cost_1'] + inputs['cost_2']

    def setup(self):     
        group_ls = self.add_subsystem('ls1', om.Group(), promotes_inputs=['x','y'],
                            promotes_outputs=['cost_1']) 

        group_ls.add_subsystem('Cost1', Cost1(), promotes_inputs=['x','y'],
                           promotes_outputs=['cost_1'])
                           
        group_ls.add_subsystem('Cost2', Cost2(), promotes_inputs=['x','y'],
                           promotes_outputs=['cost_2'])
        
        self.add_subsystem('obj_cmp', self.ObjCmp(), promotes_inputs=['cost_1','cost_2'],
                           promotes_outputs=['obj'])


# build the model
prob = om.Problem(model=MDA())
model = prob.model

model.add_design_var('x', lower=0.1, upper=1)
model.add_design_var('y', lower=0.1, upper=1)
model.add_objective('obj')

# setup the optimization
prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.setup()

# run the optimization
prob.set_val('x', .5)
prob.set_val('y', .5)

prob.run_driver()

# minimum value
print(prob.get_val('obj'))

# location of the minimum
print(prob.get_val('x'))
print(prob.get_val('y'))
```